# Automatic Schema Validation using NHibernate/ActiveRecord

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

Let's assume I have a table of Products with columns: Id, Name, Price
and using NHibernate (or ActiveRecord) I map the table to the POCO:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now if someday a new column named ShipmentPrice (let's assume it's double too)
will be added to the Products table, is there any way I can automatically know that?

For saying automatically I mean adding code to do that or getting an exception?
(I assume I don't have control on the columns of the table or a way to
know of any changes to the table's schema in advance)

Answer (score 3):

You do recall correctly, Mauricio. The following code shows how you can create or update a schema. The update will run when Validate() raises an exception. No exception will be thrown when a field is available in the database but not in the configuration. It is perfectly legal to have extra fields: you don't want them to be deleted, I hope? That could cause tremendous damage...

The following code shows Test, Create, Validate and Update, each step with the proper exception handling. The code is simplified, but it should give you a handle on how to do a validation.

This code helps with Entity-centric (POCO) ORM configurations, where you can add a field to your class and it will automatically be updated in the database. Not with table-centric, where fields are leading.

```
// executes schema script against database
private static void CreateOrUpdateSchema(Configuration config)
{
    // replace this with your test for existence of schema
    // (i.e., with SQLite, you can just test for the DB file)
    if (!File.Exists(DB_FILE_NAME))
    {
        try
        {
            SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(config);
            export.Create(false, true);
        }
        catch (HibernateException e)
        {
            // create was not successful
            // you problably want to break out your application here
            MessageBox.Show(
                String.Format("Problem while creating database: {0}", e),
                "Problem");
        }
    }
    else
    {

        // already something: validate
        SchemaValidator validator = new SchemaValidator(config);
        try
        {
            validator.Validate();
        }
        catch (HibernateException)
        {
            // not valid, try to update
            try
            {
                SchemaUpdate update = new SchemaUpdate(config);
                update.Execute(false, true);
            }
            catch (HibernateException e)
            {
                // update was not successful
                // you problably want to break out your application here
                MessageBox.Show(
                    String.Format("Problem while updating database: {0}", e),
                    "Problem");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-- Abel --

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NHibernate's SchemaValidator](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/22/nhibernate-schemavalidator.aspx), but IIRC it only checks that your mapped entities are valid so it doesn't check if there are *more* columns than mapped properties since that wouldn't really break your app.